автоматическое прочтение сообщений в ВК
хочу сделать так, чтобы в ВК (VK, VKontakte, ВКонтакте) сообщения прочитывались автоматически. без разницы, онлайн я или оффлайн (хотя бы онлайн).
Также хочу отключить или наоборот включить автоматическое прочитывание сообщений.
например, "+авточиталка" я отправляю это сообщение, код удаляет его и начинает автоматически прочитывать сообщения
"-авточиталка". я отправляю это сообщение, код его удаляет и отключает автоматически прочитывать сообщения.
буду очень рад если поможете.

Если это про программирование, значит вопрос слишком общий, потому вы не описали конкретную проблему, с которой вы столкнулись при попытке реализовать это. Если это не про программирование, значит это просто не по теме сайта

Идёте читаете доки по API VK, реализуете метод messages.read или как он там и ставите на крон например на каждые 10  минут

У вас весьма общий вопрос, который, возможно, лучше переформулировать каким-то следующим образом, например - "Какими способами реализовать автоматическое прочтение сообщений в ВК?".
То, что вы описали - можно реализовать разными способами. Но практически для всех из них нужен свой сервер, который способен выполнять автоматические запланированные задачи (cron).

Прочитать как получить доступ к АПИ ВК (Быстрый старт), скорее всего через сайт; Как получить доступ к сообщениям через АПИ ВК и метод для его прочтения (messages.markAsRead); Написать скрипт, который будет вызывать реализованный метод для прочтения сообщений каждый x времени; Добавить переменные, которые будут отвечать за включение/отключение "авточиталки"; Запустить скрипт.
Второй вариант - очень муторный и тупой, но может сработать. Если не использовать API, то скорее всего, можно попробовать использовать запрос на получение страницы списка сообщений через отправку get-запроса curl с вашими данными cookie для авторизации (Вот несколько вопросов по теме: 1, 2); Разобрать (спарсить) стили и ссылки непрочитанных сообщений из полученного результата; Отправить на страницу каждого из сообщений по get-запросу, что должно "прочитать" их; Повторять каждые x времени. Но есть нюанс, что список сообщений подгружается динамически, при прокрутке этого списка вниз, что не даст скрипту прочитать сразу все сообщения.

В итоге, куда проще и лучше - использовать официальную документацию ВК. А если что-то будет не понятно, то можно задать вопрос в техподдержку.
